# Orthogonal operator matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

We have the linear polynomial space:
$$
A = \{p\in C[0,1]\colon \ p(t)={c_0} + {c_1}t + {c_2}{t^2} + {c_3}{t^3},\ {c_j} \in \mathbb{R}\} 
$$
and the linear operator $B\colon A\to A$ defined as $$B\colon f(t) \mapsto P(\int\limits_0^t {f(z)dz} )
$$

Where $P$ is the orthogonal projection from $C[0,1]$ onto $A$.

**To do:**

write $B$ operator in matrix form at any basis.

**My thoughts:**

i read about orthogonal polynomial - It's definition in general:

$$(f,g) = \int\limits_a^b {f(x)g(x)w(x)dx} 
$$

so i need to transfer basis to another basis

$$(1,t,t^2,t^3)$$

to $g(x)$ that satisfies orthogonal polynomial definition. I'm right? And how i can do it?

Comment: I guess the operator $B$ is defined on $A$, right?

Comment: Yes, it's defined on A

Comment: "orthogonal projection on $A$": the parent space is $C[0,1]$ with the standard inner product?

Comment: Yes, you are correct absolutely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extended hint: to get a matrix of $B$ in a basis you need to know where $B$ maps the basic vectors to. Taking $\{1,t,t^2,t^3\}$ as a basis, we see that we do not need to project the first three basic vectors since the integral is already in $A$. The only you have to find out is $p(t)=B(t^3)=P(t^4/4)$. You can find it by definition as $p(t)-t^4/4$ should be orthogonal to $A$. It gives you the linear system to solve (4 equations and 4 unknown coefficients of $p$)
$$
\int_0^1 (p(t)-\frac{t^4}{4})t^k\,dt=0,\quad \forall k=0,1,2,3.
$$